# What is a good regex to match for URLs in dataweave?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I tried using something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
%dw 2.0
var myString = "mycompany.com"
output application/json
---
{
    "match" : myString match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the regex you have shared and replaced **match** with **matches** as you would like to validate the url against the regex.

```
%dw 2.0
var myString = "https://www.mycompany.com"
output application/json
---
{
    "match" : myString matches (/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()\/@:%_\+.~#?&=]*)/)
}
```